# Azure Functions Tab not showing in VSCode

Tags: azure, function

I have installed Azure Functions in VSCode:

[vscode installed extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXHuq.png)

But I cannot see it in the Azure tab on the left hand side:

[azure tab open w/o functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AcPT.png)

And it does not show in the submenu either:

[submenu w/o functions option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz1YY.png)

I have used Azure Functions on this laptop before, and have created JS functions before. But now I need to create a new function for a new app and cannot figure out why it is not working. I have tried to uninstall the extension and reinstall it, to sign out of VSCode and resign in, but with no luck. Not sure why it stopped working after a bit of not using it, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of VS Code **Azure Extension** contains below Tabs.

[image]

You can see the Azure function in **Workspace** Tab

[image]

When you click on the deploy icon it will ask you to deploy whether Azure **Function App** or **Web App**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Microsoft should update [their tutorial to reflect this change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=nodejs)

Comment: @zach-m sorry, we were caught a little flat-footed with this major Azure extension improvement, but the updates are nearly complete. Thanks for letting us know.